# How to pass query parameters with spaces in Open API 3

Tags: query-string, openapi, openapi-3-0

I have query parameter http://localhost:8080/test?username=User Name . Below is the spec used

```
  /test:
    get:
      description: Pass name
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          allowReserved: true
```

the spec validation is failing with "bad request" error when the query parameter contains spaces.
how to pass spaces in query paramer in Open API 3

Answer (score 0):

Escape the space!

```
http://localhost:8080/test?username=User%20Name
```

you can use `encodeURIComponent` to do that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Here my use case is that, the spaces cannot be url encoded. that is the url should be http://localhost:8080/test?username=User Name

Comment: Hmm, why can't you url encode your spcaces?

Comment: This is the  use case .I see from https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/ that spaceDelimited  option is available for query.  but unsure how to use it

Comment: That is not what `spaceDelimited` means. That is an option for passing arrays, not simple strings. And even if you were sending an array, it's still expected to be uri encoded, as the docs you linked state.